# background images is not showing

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have this webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {}
        }]
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The file structure of my react app is as following:

```
dist
..assets
...bundle.js
..index.html
src
..components
..pages
..images
..App.js
..index.js
..style.css
```

I am trying to set the background image of a page using css as

```
[page-selector]{
 background: url('./images/someimage.jpg')
}
```

but it doesn't show. I suspect it's about the relative path of the image or the appropriate loader and its options, but I don't know what it is exactly and how to solve it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Open your `index.html` file in browser and inspect the styles of that `[page-selector]` element, what do you see over the `Styles` panel?

Comment: @chenxsan The problem was fixed by adding `url-loader` instead of the `file-loader` by adding the following rule to webpack.config.js file`{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
      },`